# Should I use elseif and close the database connection somewhere?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there is a better way to write my code below. Basically two questions, should I use `elseif` and do I need to close the connection with the database somewhere?

Thank you

**UPDATED CODE**

```
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) === 1) {


    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($member['disabled']) {
        header("location: not-allowed.php");
        exit();
        }

    if (!$member['verified']) {
        header("location: please-verify.php");
        exit();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can there ever be more than one result? Do you query by a unique key?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Yes there will be only one result ever.

Comment: Then why check any result count at all -  you can just do the usual `while(fetch...)` loop, and inside the loop you set a flag when you decide the login was successful. After the loop you simply test for the flag.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I have updated my code. Don't you think that now is simple enough for changing it ?

Comment: You could even say `if ($result && $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` now...

Comment: what's the point in new edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not repeat yourself

```
if (!($result && mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)) redirect("login-failed.php");
$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($member['disabled']) redirect("not-allowed.php");
if (!$member['verified']) redirect("please-verify.php");
if ( ($member['expires']) && ($member['expires'] <= time()) ) redirect("expired.php");
if ( ($_SESSION['SESS_TOKEN'] == $_POST['token']) ) redirect("member-index.php");

function redirect($location){
    header("location: $location");
    exit();
}
```

No, if you're using `exit` or `return` there is no need for else.

No, it's unnecessary to close mysql connection manually.

Comment: I got on error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting '('  on `!($result && mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)`

Comment: oh yeah, additional pair of parenthesis required. quite ugly but works

Comment: @Nikolai there is nothing speed-wise in such a code, whatever written. it's not a place which will affect your performance by any means

Comment: I have to look after other things then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) === 1)
{
    ...
}
else die('Wrong username and/or password');
```

Comment: What if I replace die() with         `header("location: login-failed.php");
        exit();` ?

Comment: You'll have to put those in brackets again, but yes - it will work.

Comment: I think your comment is for my previous comment

Comment: Well, yes - that's where you asked about it :)

Comment: Ok, one last thing before accepting your answer. I have updated the code in the question. Should I close the database connection somewhere or it doesn't matter (meaning that it closes by itself).

Comment: If it's a persistent connection (if you've used `mysql_pconnect()`) - no. Otherwise - yes, you should close it.